# Transform dataframe in R: Resolve ambiguity, save rows

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation, reshape

I want to transform a dataframe from this

```
original <-data.frame(Treatment=c("Drug","Drug","Drug","Placebo","Placebo","Placebo"),Group=c(1,2,3,1,2,3),Performance=c(4,6,3,2,5,1))
```

to this:

```
transformed <- data.frame(Group=c(1,2,3),PerformanceDrug=c(4,6,3),PerformanceTreatment=c(2,5,1))
```

I tried the melt-function from package reshape, but didn't come to a solution yet. Can you help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data are already "molten", so just use `dcast`:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(original, Group ~ Treatment, value.var="Performance")
#   Group Drug Placebo
# 1     1    4       2
# 2     2    6       5
# 3     3    3       1
```

You can also do this directly with base R's `reshape()`:

```
reshape(original, direction = "wide", idvar="Group", timevar="Treatment")
#   Group Performance.Drug Performance.Placebo
# 1     1                4                   2
# 2     2                6                   5
# 3     3                3                   1
```

And, a final option:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
original %>% spread(Treatment, Performance)
```

Comment: @akrun, will I get another +1 if I add `xtabs(Performance ~ Group + Treatment, original)` to the options :-)

Comment: Well, probably somebody else will as I can't double vote